# error in storing elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11

I am trying to store the numbers which is of type string into a 2D array. While storing string as a number it is not storing it at all but showing `0000`.

```
while(m<sm)             /*storing string into integer array */
 {
    if(isdigit(input4[m]))      /* string to 2D array conversion*/
    {
        K=input4[m]-'0';
        K1=input4[m+2]-'0'; // changed from m+1 to m+2
        cout<<K<<"\t"<<K1;
       arr[K][K1]=2;
    cout<<"\n";
    }

    m++;

 }

 for(int i =0; i<input1 ;i++){
    for(int j =0;j<input2;j++){
        cout<<arr[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
 }
```

INPUT:
2,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,1,3

OUTPUT:
2   1
1   -4
2   2
2   -4
3   2
2   -4
2   2
2   -4
2   3
3   -4
2   3
3   -4
3   3
3   -4
1   3
3   -7
0000
0001
0111
0011

My question is what is that second column? It is supposed to be:
2 1
2 2
3 2
and so on because these are the values of K and K1. I want to store the elements which is in the form of a string into 2D array by talking two regular elements a a coordinate of a matrix and then i want to store 1 at the coordinates K and K1. Its storing 1 only on 6 coordinates but is must be on 8 coordinates as per the input.

Comment: Did you debug your program statement by statement? Also I couldn't reproduce. Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: @FirstStep: `isdigit` is a standard C function.

Comment: yep. i have used bits/stdc++.h an header file and isdigit is working perfectly fine i have debug it there is no problem in it but i dont knoow why it is not storing 1 at the coordinate places

Comment: @DeepakMalhotra: that's not a standard header, `isdigit` comes from `<cstdlib>`. But that's an unrelated problem (which is why this is a comment, not an answer)

Comment: @DeepakMalhotra Not the compiler to check for compiler error but the debugger which lets you walk through the executing code.   It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Also, post your **real** code. This code doesn't match the claimed output. You store `2` but print `1`.

Comment: Note that your first "coordinate" is `2,1`, the second `1,2`, the third `2,2`, the fourth `2,3`, and so on (`K1` in one iteration will be `K` in the next). And unless `sm` is two units smaller than the size of `input4`, you're accessing it out-of-bounds, which is undefined. And you're storing `2`, not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that K1 is negative (as you can see), which means that you have an out-of-bounds access of `arr[K][K1]`. Clearly `input4[m + 1]` is NOT a digit, and it appears to be the comma separating your digits.

Comment: i have made a change in the code. i have changed m+1 to m+2.

Comment: yes in stores 1 at coordinates but only on 6 coordinates but the total number of coordinates are 8.

Comment: @DeepakMalhotra: I'll leave that for you to figure out, glad to see that your C++ problem is solved.

Comment: No the total number of coordinates are 8 but it stores 1 only on 6 coordinates. what about other two coordinates?